# how to re categorize all the articles on my site

Tags: url, blog

I started a blog some months before. I tried to maintain them in a proper category. So people can search/get contents easily. But now i feel, all the articles are being messed up.

Please suggest a way, i can categorize them. And i must have not to face 404 problem.

Currently there are around 120 articles on my site.

Please suggest any generic list of category and subcategory which can suite to most of the website , if someone has..

Thanks in advance

Comment: No list of categories and subcategories will work for "most websites". You can't make that sort of thing generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not here to run your site for you. You should decide what categories best suit your site, based on the articles you currently have (and the types of articles you plan to have in the future).

Regarding the "404 problem", all you need to is redirect all the old URLs to the new ones. If you only change the names of a category (e.g. `oldcategory/article` to `newcategory/article`) you can use a more generic rewrite rule.

If articles have moved to all different categories (e.g. `oldcategory/article1` to `newcat1/article1` and `oldcategory/article2` to `newcat2/article2`) then you will need to redirect individual articles.

Comment: I was looking for a generic list not only for my site. I found the same some day ago. But missed it. So i believe that people can suggest more better and generic answer.

Comment: @articlestack: But it depends entirely on your web site and its content. If your blog is about kittens you wouldn't have an "HTML" category. Even if it's a technology blog an HTML category could be too specific. Sorry if you think its a cop-out but you have to decide for yourself!

Comment: Might be, i am not able to answer properly because i am example less this time. I'll try to make some example to clarify my need and question